# SQL while inserting into temp tables error stating already exist but I clean up tables prior

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure why this is happening, but when I run some code that takes a long multi-value sub-value string, I'm getting a random error. The error is supposedly that I'm trying to do a insert into a temp table that already exists, though I'm not sure how this is possible since inside the top of the first base loop, I'm dropping the tables if they do exist. That way the prior run can use them, them drop and run through again if need be.

Now I'm almost certain another error is failing, then causing a misleading return message but not sure.

Here is the full stored procedure. Also, I'm a stack dev so if you have any good pointers for this query please feel free to make note. Thanks in advance.

DATA string for testing that would possibly come into this procedure:

> MITUTOYO~103-217~DESC~ ^BROWN & SHARPE~73~DESC~ ^MITUTOYO~103-188~DESC~ ^MITUTOYO~103-224A~DESC~ ^MITUTOYO~103-225A~DESC~ ^MITUTOYO~103-225A~DESC~ ^MITUTOYO~103-189A~DESC~ ^

For each one of the main multi values within the ^ character, we would look up the Manufacturer and Model and see if it exist. If so return it, if not return it with a new suggestions list of multi-values in the suggestionsList column. Here is the example of one item sent in, then no matches found so does the fuzzy lookup.

> Manufacturer  ManufacturerPartNumber  ManufacturerDescription Price   ItemType    MfrFound    ModelFound  Score   SuggestionGroup
>
> Analyzer Network, 0.00, NA, 0, 1, 0, STANDARD,,USE FOR HYPRO STANDARD BORE
> GAGES,31.00,6, ^ Harvey Wells,,FORCE GAUGE 0 35 GMS,93.50,0, ^

The full stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DATA_FuzzyAssetMatchLARGE
/*
    PROP: @LISTIN - The entire multi file string sent in from the data file of records.
    I=Since the records sent in are a multi value record of sub values meaning (v1.Mfr, v1.Model, v1.Description ^ v2.Mfr, v2.Model, v2.Description ^ ....)
    we could in theory have thousands of records to n(3) of string length unknown (n). This being said, we set the value to varchar(max).
    
    varchar(max) unlike varchar which holds (8000 characters max about 65k bytes), varchar(max) can hold 2 gigs worth of data. That equates to about
    1 billion characters since in .NET and others one CHAR is a 2 byte system. This holds more than enough.
*/
@LISTIN VARCHAR(MAX)
 AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   SET ARITHABORT OFF 
   SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
   SET FMTONLY OFF

declare @errorMessage varchar(150) -- ideally would be nice to append to each row so we knew what failed but not break and continue. Not like that at moment

-- ITEMS USED FOR TOP LEVEL RECURSIVE SPLIT LOOP --    
declare @pos INT;
declare @len INT;
declare @value varchar(max); -- the value of the first splits (objects) delimed by the ^ character
-- Counter variables used to loop and build the one column Suggestion of all matching items
declare @MaxCount integer;
declare @Count integer;
declare @suggestionsStringBuilder varchar(350); --holds the built list of any suggestions.
declare @objectManufacturer varchar(100);
declare @objectModel varchar(150);
declare @objectDescription varchar(150);  --the context for this instance to run the params selects for Mfr, Model, Desc
declare @counterIndex int = 0;
declare @objectString varchar(250);
--USED FOR SECOND LEVEL RECURSIVE SPLIT LOOP
declare @objectPosVal INT;
declare @objectLenVal INT;
declare @objectSubstring varchar(250); -- the value used for the secondary split (each object properties such as the actual Mfr, Model, Description, so on....)

--cursor declarations
DECLARE @suggestionsListCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @CURSOR_Mfr varchar(150);
DECLARE @CURSOR_Model varchar(150);
DECLARE @CURSOR_Desc varchar(150);
DECLARE @CURSOR_Type varchar(20);
DECLARE @CURSOR_Price MONEY;
DECLARE @CURSOR_Score int;

--TEMP TABLE TO STORE FUZZY PREDFINED TABLES IN
IF OBJECT_ID('BASE') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE BASE

--CREATE THE TEMPTABLE TO WORK WITH
CREATE TABLE BASE
(
    Manufacturer varchar(150) null, 
    ManufacturerPartNumber Varchar(100) null, 
    ManufacturerDescription varchar(150) null,
    Score int ,
    Price money,
    ItemType varchar(20),
    ModelFound bit not null,
    MfrFound bit not null, 
    SuggestionGroup varchar(MAX) null 
)


--THIS IS THE LOOP TO PREPARE THE DELIM STRING AND DO A FUZZY MATH OR STRAIGHT MATCH ON EACH OBJECT ROW
set @pos = 0;
set @len = 0;

while charindex('^', @LISTIN, @pos+1)>0
    begin
    if object_id('tempdb..#TEMPPMFR') is not null drop table #TEMPPMFR
    if object_id('tmpdb..#TEMPPMFRMODEL') is not null drop table #TEMPPMFRMODEL
    
    -- stop if there was an error --
    if(@errorMessage is not null and @errorMessage  != '')
        break;
    
    set @suggestionsStringBuilder = '';
    set @len = charindex('^', @LISTIN, @pos+1) - @pos;
    set @VALUE = substring(@LISTIN,@POS,@LEN-1); 
    set @objectLenVal = 0;
    set @objectPosVal = 0;
    set @counterIndex = 0;
    
    
    set @suggestionsStringBuilder = ''
    set @objectManufacturer = ''
    set @objectModel = ''
    set @objectDescription = ''
    
    --THE LIST COMING IN IS A MULTI-DEMENSIONAL ARRAY OR MULTI-VALUE. IT IS A GROUP OF ENTITYIES, THEN EACH
    --ENTITYT IS A GROUP OF PROPERTIES. OUR OUTTER LOOP WE SPLIT ON ENTITITIES.
    -- EXAMPLE: @F, @M, @D = Manufacturer, odel, Description
    while charindex('~', @value, @objectPosVal+1)>0
        begin
            set @objectLenVal = charindex('~', @value, @objectPosVal+1) - @objectPosVal
            set @objectSubstring = substring(@value, @objectPosVal, @objectLenVal)
                            
            if(@counterIndex=0) 
                set @objectManufacturer = LTRIM(RTRIM(@objectSubstring)) 
            else if(@counterIndex=1) 
                set @objectModel = LTRIM(RTRIM(@objectSubstring))
            else 
                begin
                set @objectDescription = LTRIM(RTRIM(@objectSubstring)) 
                break 
                end
                        
            set @objectPosVal = charindex('~', @value, @objectPosVal+@objectLenVal) +1
        end 
        
        -- ****
        -- **** WE HAVE THE MANUFACTURER AND THE MODEL SO JUST RETURN THE DATA 
        -- ****
        if((select top 1 1 FROM Products_OurProducts_Products where Manufacturer = @objectManufacturer and ManufacturerPartNumber = @objectModel) > 0)
            begin try  
                insert into BASE (
                     Manufacturer
                    ,ManufacturerPartNumber
                    ,ManufacturerDescription
                    ,Price,ItemType
                    ,MfrFound
                    ,ModelFound
                    ,Score
                    ,SuggestionGroup
                ) 
                select 
                    POP.Manufacturer
                    ,POP.ManufacturerPartNumber as Model
                    ,POP.Description
                    ,CONVERT(money,POP.Price) as Price
                    ,POP.ItemType
                    ,CAST('1' as bit) as MfrFound
                    ,CAST('1' as bit) as ModelFound
                    ,CAST('-1' as int) as Score
                    ,'' as SuggestionGroup  
                from 
                    Products_OurProducts_Products as POP
                where 
                    POP.Manufacturer = @objectManufacturer 
                        and 
                    POP.ManufacturerPartNumber = @objectManufacturer        
            end try  
            begin catch
                SET @errorMessage = (
                    select  
                        'Number: ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() as varchar(15)) +  ' Message:' + ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
                    ); 
            end catch
        else
        -- ****
        -- **** WE EITHER FOUND MANUFACTURER SO FUZZY ON MODEL OR VICE VERSA
        -- ****
            begin try 
                if((select top 1 1 from Products_OurProducts_Products where Manufacturer = @objectManufacturer) > 0)
                    begin
                    --we have to build these temp tables os dynamic columns exist such as MfrFound, ModelFound              
                    select 
                        PMFR.Manufacturer
                        ,PMFR.ManufacturerPartNumber
                        ,PMFR.Description AS ManufacturerDescription
                        ,convert(money,PMFR.Price) as Price
                        ,PMFR.ItemType
                        ,cast('1' as bit) as MfrFound
                        ,cast('0' as bit) as ModelFound
                        ,'' as SuggestionGroup
                    into 
                        #TEMPPMFR
                    from 
                        Products_OurProducts_Products as PMFR
                    where 
                        PMFR.Manufacturer = @objectManufacturer
                        
                    set @SuggestionsListCursor = cursor for
                        select top 5 
                            P.Manufacturer
                           ,P.ManufacturerPartNumber as Model
                           ,P.ManufacturerDescription AS 'Description'
                           ,P.Price
                           ,fms.score as Score
                        from #TEMPPMFR as P
                            cross apply (
                                select 
                                    dbo.FuzzyControlMatch(@objectModel, P.ManufacturerPartNumber) AS score
                                ) as fms
                        where 
                            P.Manufacturer = @objectManufacturer
                        order by 
                            fms.score 
                        desc
                               
                    open @SuggestionsListCursor 
                    
                    fetch next from 
                        @SuggestionsListCursor 
                    into 
                        @CURSOR_Mfr
                       ,@CURSOR_Model
                       ,@CURSOR_Desc
                       ,@CURSOR_Price
                       ,@CURSOR_Score
                        
                    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                    begin
                        if @suggestionsStringBuilder!='' 
                            set @suggestionsStringBuilder=@suggestionsStringBuilder + @CURSOR_Mfr + ',' + @CURSOR_Model + ',' + @CURSOR_Desc + ',' + convert(varchar(20),@CURSOR_Price) + ',' + convert(varchar(4),@CURSOR_Score) + ', ^ '  
                        else 
                            set @suggestionsStringBuilder = @CURSOR_Mfr + ',' + @CURSOR_Model + ',' + @CURSOR_Desc + ',' + convert(varchar(20),@CURSOR_Price) + ',' + convert(varchar(4),@CURSOR_Score) + ', ^ '
                                
                        fetch next from 
                            @SuggestionsListCursor 
                        into 
                            @CURSOR_Mfr
                           ,@CURSOR_Model
                           ,@CURSOR_Desc
                           ,@CURSOR_Price
                           ,@CURSOR_Score
                    end
                            
                    --Now we insert the original Mfr, Model, Desc, and the suggestions list we build
                    insert into BASE values(
                        @objectManufacturer
                       ,@objectModel
                       ,@objectDescription
                       ,'0'
                       ,'0'
                       ,'NA'
                       ,'1'
                       ,'0'
                       ,@suggestionsStringBuilder
                     )
                    
                    close @SuggestionsListCursor
                    deallocate @SuggestionsListCursor
                end
                else
                    --IF HAVE A FUZZY AT MFR, THEN WE NEED TO GRAB BEST CHOICE AND GO DOWN. 
                    --WE COULD HAVE POSIBLY CANDIDATES FOR THIS SO WHEN TO STOP RECURSIVENESS AND SAY ADDING NEW ENTRY? 
                    begin
                    --AT MOMENT JUST RETURN TOP FOUND MFR THEN SELECT FROM THAT TO SEE RESULT TESTS
                    --FIRST LETS SEE IF SENT MODEL EXIST AND IF SO, PULL THAT THEN RANK AGAINST MFR FOR IT
                    if((select top 1 1 from Products_OurProducts_Products where ManufacturerPartNumber = @objectModel) > 0)
                        begin
                            select 
                                Manufacturer
                               ,ManufacturerPartNumber
                               ,Description AS ManufacturerDescription
                               ,CONVERT(money,Price) AS Price
                               ,ItemType
                               ,CAST('0' as bit) as MfrFound
                               ,CAST('1' as bit) as ModelFound
                               ,'' as SuggestionGroup 
                             into 
                                #TEMPPMFRMODEL
                             from 
                                Products_OurProducts_Products
                             where 
                                ManufacturerPartNumber = @objectModel
                                
                             set @SuggestionsListCursor = cursor for 
                                    select top 5 
                                        P.Manufacturer
                                       ,P.ManufacturerPartNumber as Model
                                       ,P.ManufacturerDescription as 'Description'
                                       ,P.Price
                                       ,fms.score as Score
                                    from #TEMPPMFRMODEL AS P
                                        CROSS APPLY (
                                            select 
                                                dbo.FuzzyControlMatch(@objectManufacturer, P.Manufacturer) AS score
                                            ) AS fms
                                    where 
                                        P.ManufacturerPartNumber = @objectModel
                                    order by 
                                        fms.score 
                                    desc
                                    
                                --OPEN CURSOR NOW--
                                open @SuggestionsListCursor
                                
                                -- NOW LOOP THE RESULTS AND BUILD DEMLIMETER STRING OF SUGESTIONS FOR MFR-- 
                                fetch next from @SuggestionsListCursor into @CURSOR_Mfr, @CURSOR_Model, @CURSOR_Desc, @CURSOR_Price, @CURSOR_Score 
                                
                                while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                                    begin
                                        if @suggestionsStringBuilder != '' 
                                            set @suggestionsStringBuilder = @suggestionsStringBuilder + @CURSOR_Mfr + ',' + @CURSOR_Model + ',' + @CURSOR_Desc + ',' + convert(varchar(20),@CURSOR_Price) + ',' + convert(varchar(4),@CURSOR_Score) + ', ^ '  
                                        else 
                                            set @suggestionsStringBuilder = @CURSOR_Mfr + ',' + @CURSOR_Model + ',' + @CURSOR_Desc + ',' + convert(varchar(20),@CURSOR_Price) + ',' + convert(varchar(4),@CURSOR_Score) + ', ^ '
                                    
                                        fetch next from @SuggestionsListCursor 
                                        into @CURSOR_Mfr, @CURSOR_Model, @CURSOR_Desc, @CURSOR_Price, @CURSOR_Score
                                    end
                                
                                insert into BASE values(
                                    @objectManufacturer
                                   ,@objectModel
                                   ,@objectDescription
                                   ,'0'
                                   ,'0'
                                   ,'NA'
                                   ,'1'
                                   ,'0'
                                   ,@suggestionsStringBuilder
                                  )
                                  
                                close @SuggestionsListCursor ;
                                deallocate @SuggestionsListCursor ;
                            end
                    else
                        insert into BASE values(
                            @objectManufacturer
                            ,@objectModel
                            ,@objectDescription
                            ,'0'
                            ,'0'
                            ,'NA'
                            ,'0'
                            , '0'
                            , ''
                        )       
                    end
                    --THEN SEE IF EXIST USING FUZZY FOUND MFR, TO SEEK MODEL NUMBER ETC.
            END TRY  
            BEGIN CATCH
                SET @errorMessage = (
                    select  
                        'Number: ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() as varchar(15)) +  ' Message:' + ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
                    );  
            END CATCH
                
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX('^', @LISTIN, @pos+@len) +1
    END
    
 if(@errorMessage is not null and @errorMessage != '')
        select @errorMessage as 'ErrorInfo'
else
    select 
        Manufacturer
        ,ManufacturerPartNumber
        ,ManufacturerDescription
        ,Price
        ,ItemType
        ,MfrFound
        ,ModelFound
        ,Score
        ,SuggestionGroup 
    from 
        BASE
  
--NOW REMOVE THE TEMP TABLE
If(OBJECT_ID('BASE') Is Not Null)
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE BASE
    END
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMPPMFR') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TEMPPMFR
    END
IF(OBJECT_ID('tmpdb..#TEMPPMFRMODEL') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN 
        DROP TABLE #TEMPPMFRMODEL 
    END
 END
 GO
```

Comment: `tmpdb` instead of `tempdb`...

Comment: Are you serious. Jesse, thanks.

Comment: So sorry i didnt see that one, but it has gotten me and co-workers in past in C and python. lol Thanks again.

Comment: No need to be sorry. Such things happen. ;)

Comment: sql server is really good at retrieving data. But it is really awful as a programming language. What you have here is procedural code with loops nested at least 4 deep. I don't even want to try to unravel what this code is doing but t-sql is the wrong tool for this job. If you really that much logic doing this in CLR is likely going to be better. But I have a feeling this could be rewritten as a set based approach instead RBAR (row by agonizing row).